# Screens stopped working through dock station

Tags: video, dock

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell laptop with a Targus dock station (model 412). I have the dock station connected to the laptop through usb-c, and one HDMI and one VGA connected to the dock. It was working properly (for 2 years) and this morning it has suddenly stopped working. If I plug USB devices to the dock station they work properly.

I have tried unplugging all the connectors but everything looks fine. If I connect the HDMI screen directly to the laptop it works properly.

Any advice for a more thorough check?

Thank you.

Comment: The dock is burned out?

Comment: I don't think so, usb ports work properly

Comment: Just because one part works does not mean another part is not burned out.

Comment: how do I check that, with an ammeter?

Comment: no idea what an ammeter is sorry.

Comment: An [ammeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter) is used to measure 
electrical current.  It might help diagnose a hardware fault if you know what you are looking for but I'd suspect a software issue, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

`dmesg` can be used to examine the kernel logs for error messages related to drivers... This might help you.